# IBM Worklight Liberty Farm Config issue and log

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty, worklight-runtime

Environment:

1. IBM Worklight Server 6.2 * 2,
2. Liberty Server 8.5.5.1 * 2&
3. IBM DB2 * 1.

Both Worklight Server nodes are working.

**Problem:**

1. Whenever the console URL[http://x.x.x.x:9080/worklightconsole] has tried to open it takes time to load[Approx 10 Secs.], I have tried by restarting the server and tried many times.
2. Is there any influence of the following two properties in Liberty Farm implementation.

   A. cluster.data.synchronization.taskFrequencyInSeconds &

   B. clustersynctask.staleCyclesNum
3. Trace.log -  Can this be ignored?

   A. When Liberty Farm is configured why I am getting Liberty Profile Runtime? When I browse through the trace.log further then I could find the **Detected Liberty Farm Runtime**.

   B. Why the warning is Impossible to decode the password?

   C. No where I specified in my configuration as **Localhost**?

> [10/22/14 10:26:06:642 GST] 00000013 id=
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory          1
>   **Detected Liberty profile runtime**
>
> [10/22/14 10:26:06:643 GST] 00000013 id=
>   LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler                                   >
>   getMBeansServerConnection() ENTRY localhost null
>
> [10/22/14 10:26:06:643 GST] 00000013 id=
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     1
>   Worklight REST **connection with port 9444 on localhost**
>
> [10/22/14 10:26:06:644 GST] 00000013 id=         RuntimeMBeanHandler
>   decode() ENTRY
>
> [10/22/14 10:26:06:646 GST] 00000013 id=
>   com.worklight.common.util.jmx.RuntimeMBeanHandler            W
>   **Impossible to decode the password**
>
> [10/22/14 10:26:06:646 GST] 00000013 id=         RuntimeMBeanHandler
>   decode() RETURN

Answer (score 1):

1) The console needs to wait for the sync task that is performed when starting the nodes to finish. Be sure also you have installed the latest 6.2 ifix since it includes performance improvement

2 ) No influence at all

3 A) This trace concerns the local communication between the runtime and the admin service (see next point) and in this case the important thing is the app server not the topology (communication is the same in a server farm than in a standalone Liberty server)

3 B) The WL runtime needs to communicate to the admin service that runs in the same JVM. So it makes a JMX communication on localhost with the HTTPS port number declared in server.xml

3 C) It means that the com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil jar file that is referenced in classloader element of the runtime and the admin service is not the right one or is missing in the runtime definition (defect that is fixed in the latest 6.2 ifixes). The name of the jar contains the version number that depends on the Liberty version. The jar can be found in the lib directory of Liberty. With Liberty 8.5.5.1 it should be com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.2.jar.

Comment: As you told, 1. Let me check the Latest Ifix. 2, No need to configure cluster.data.synchronization.taskFrequencyInSeconds in Liberty Farm implementation. 3(c) com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.2.jar is present in lib directory of the Liberty and also it is referenced in Class loader element of the runtime and admin services, then why the log says impossible to decode the password?

Comment: "Impossible to decode the password" is emitted when the com.ibm.websphere.crypto.PasswordUtil class is not found. So there is surely something wrong in the server.xml file

Comment: I know that something wrong. That's why trying to figure out. <classloader delegation="parentLast"><commonLibrary><fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.2.jar"/></commonLibrary></classloader> is set under the application element of Worklightadmin.war.

Comment: You must have the same com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.2.jar include for the application that references the Worklight runtime.

Comment: I am repeating again that i have included those for the runtime as well. What else you want me to do?

Comment: Must have the server.xml file.

Comment: do u want me to share server.xml